# How do I print out a variable amount of pages in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying get this to work so I can print the amount of pages that there are orders.
I declared this in its own variable but it seems not to work.
What I basicly did is generate an amount of pivottables which are declared in another tab.
These will loop through and fill these out and fill out "(blank)" when there is no "order" to display keep the pages clean. After that I filter out unnecessary materials.

But then when I want to print out I count the amount of orders in another tab. This Integer I tried to pass in the "To" variable of the PrintOut statement. But this seems to generate a runtime 1004 error.

```
Sub UpdatePivotTables()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim rngOrders As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim tableIndex As Integer
    Dim orderField As PivotField
    Dim orderItem As PivotItem
    Dim orderValue As String
    Dim printPages As Integer

    ' Set the worksheet and range containing the orders
    Set ws = Worksheets("Orderoverzicht")
    Set rngOrders = ws.Range("A5:A35")

    ' Move the active cell to a different location
    ws.Activate
    ws.Range("A1").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Loop through each pivot table and update the "Order" field
    For tableIndex = 2 To 30
        ' Find the pivot table with the corresponding name
        Set pt = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
            Set pt = Worksheets("Requirementsheets").PivotTables("Order" & tableIndex)
        On Error GoTo 0

        ' Check if a pivot table was found and the name matches
        If Not pt Is Nothing And pt.Name = "Order" & tableIndex Then
            Debug.Print "Updating PivotTable: " & pt.Name & ", Order Value: " & orderValue
            ' Check if there is a corresponding cell for the table index
            If tableIndex <= rngOrders.Cells.Count Then
                ' Get the cell with the corresponding index
                Set cell = rngOrders.Cells(tableIndex)

                ' Get the order value from the cell as a string
                orderValue = cell.Value

                ' Find the "Order" field in the pivot table
                Set orderField = pt.PivotFields("Order")

                ' Clear any existing filters in the "Order" field
                On Error Resume Next
                orderField.ClearAllFilters
                On Error GoTo 0

                If orderValue = "" Then
                    orderValue = "(blank)"
                    orderField.CurrentPage = orderValue
                End If

                ' Filter the pivot table using the order value
                On Error Resume Next
                orderField.CurrentPage = orderValue
                On Error GoTo 0

                ' Set the filter to apply to the PivotTable
                pt.RefreshTable
            End If
            
            With pt.PivotFields("Material Group Name")
                .PivotItems("Bulk Lub. Interm. Cd").Visible = False
                .PivotItems("Empty Pack.Material").Visible = False
                .PivotItems("One Way IBC").Visible = False
                .PivotItems("Pallets").Visible = False
                .PivotItems("#N/A").Visible = False
                .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
                .PivotItems("Base Oil Group II").Visible = False
                .PivotItems("Pump Off IBC").Visible = False
                .PivotItems("Special Products").Visible = False
                .PivotItems("Base Oil Group I").Visible = False
                .PivotItems("Base Oil Group III").Visible = False
                .PivotItems("Additives Bulk").Visible = False
                .PivotItems("Packed Lubes").Visible = False
            End With
            
            With pt.PivotFields("Material")
                .PivotItems("88022000").Visible = False
            End With
        End If
    Next tableIndex

    ' Optional: Refresh all pivot tables after updating the fields
    Set ws = Worksheets("Orderoverzicht")
    printPages = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("A5:A1000"), ">1")

    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set ws = Worksheets("Requirementsheets")

    ws.Activate
    ws.Range("A1").Select

    ws.PrintOut From:=2, To:=printPages, Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

End Sub
```

I just really tried this line but also tried to fully write out the worksheets but it doesn't seem to make any difference in this line.

`ws.PrintOut From:=2, To:=printPages, Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False`

Answer (score 1):

The reason it didn't work was that ">1" didn't fulfill the if statement of the

```
`countif.printPages = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("A5:A1000"), ">1")`
```

Because it the numbers I used where formatted as strings. Because all our ordernumbers start with the sequence "723" is added a wildcard "723*".

```
printPages = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("A5:A1000"), "723*")
```

this fixed the issue as it now was counted correctly.

Moral of the story always check the formatting of your values.